# newly appended elements disappear after reloading the page (jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, append, refresh

I used jQuery's `.append()` to add new `li` elements to a `ul` on `success` in an AJAX call. The problem is, whenever I refresh the page, the newly appended list items disappear.

I've read this has to do with refreshing the original page, and that some options are to use cookies (PHP or jQuery). I also saw something about `localStorage`. I'm not using HTML5, if that matters.

What is the best way to go about this? If I use PHP, can I embed the script inside of jQuery? Is there a more elegant way of going about this?

Thanks

Edit: included code

AJAX

```
$.ajax ({
type: 'post',
url: '/classes/resources/addResource.php',
data: {
    recName: $('#recName').val(),
    recURL: $('#recURL').val()
},
success: function(data) {
    if (data === 'added') {
        var h3ID = $('#categoryList option:selected').val();
        var title = $('#recName').val();
        var url = $('#recURL').val();
        var newListItem = '<li><a href=\"' + url + '\">' + title + '</a></li>';
        $('ul#' + h3ID).append(newListItem);
        $('span#resError').fadeIn(400).text('Resource added successfully. Add another?');
   }
   else
       $('span#resError').fadeIn(400).text('There was an error adding this resource');
   }
});
```

HTML

```
<h3 class="category" id="1">
    Category 1
</h3>
<ul id="1">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
</ul>
```

When I add List item 5 and so on, I want those new list items to remain upon refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you build your page dynamically using ajax / javascript, you need to store the current state so that you can build it exactly the same way when the page is reloaded.

There are several ways to do that like sessions (server-side) or cookies / localStorage if the information you need to build the page is stored on the client side.

If you are not using html5 but you are using ajax to build the page, using sessions and doing everything server-side is probably the easiest option. Just store the current / updated state of the page every time an ajax request is made.

An additional consideration is how long the information has to persist. If you use the standard php session mechanism, your session / state will be lost pretty fast (about an hour without reloading / refreshing I think with the default settings).

Comment: Thank you. Most of the page was rendered by me just writing HTML. I have several unordered lists, and I want the newly-added list items to persist indefinitely (the lists are for a bunch of URLs).

Comment: @NojoRu It is hard to tell without seeing any code or example, but it would seem you need to add newly added list items (all items...) to a database and build the page from that.

Comment: @NojoRu I all depends on where the original list comes from. I suppose that is a database, so that is where the newly added items need to get added.

Comment: Storing a user's state in a database sounds like overkill to me. Check out front-end scripts like PersistJS, maybe? https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js
This would let you easily use local storage with excellent cross-browser support.

But if there are only a fairly limited variety of possible states, a more PHP-oriented solution (as suggested) might be easy enough. Could you update the URL when the AJAX query happens, then check that back-end to see what state the user is in?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy You could be right, hard to tell without more context.